# Strange toolbar icon in AUCTeX mode (on Mac)

Tags: auctex, tool-bar

I notice there is a strange box-shaped icon in the toolbar in the AUCTeX mode (circled in the picture below).

[image: Strange toolbar icon in AUCTeX]

It should be a toolbar separator (for example, on Linux):

[image: On Linux platform]

I am using GNU Emacs 26.1 with AUCTeX 12.1.1 on macOS 10.13.6. This problem seems to have existed for many years. [The exact same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009394/annoying-icon-in-auctex-mode) was reported in 2011. Does anyone know what causes this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Paste `(insert (propertize " " 'display (eval tool-bar-separator-image-expression)))` into the `*scratch*` buffer, place point behind the last closing parenthesis and press `C-j`. That should insert the separator image at point. Call `C-h v` `tool-bar-separator-image-expression` to get the relative file path to the separator image. For me that is `separator.xbm`. Call `C-h v image-load-path` to get the completion to an absolute path (for me: `/usr/share/emacs/26.1/etc/images/`). Search there for the image and look what you get.Compare the appearance in Emacs and in some external image program.

Comment: @Tobias Thank you. I did what you suggested. Emacs shows the separator image (in the `*scratch*` buffer) as a thin vertical bar which is exactly it should be (see [the screenshot](https://imgur.com/TNSqosG)). The separator image files (in `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/images/` with names `separator.pbm` and `separator.xpm`) show exactly the same as the one shown from executing `(insert (propertize " " 'display (eval tool-bar-separator-image-expression)))`. But it is not like the one shown on the toolbar.

Comment: @Tobias I do notice that AUCTeX carries a separator image itself (for me, it is located at `~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-12.1.1/images/sep.xpm`). But this image also shows a thin vertical bar when I view it by external image program.

Comment: Go to the buffer `1.tex` and type `M-: (nth 7 (cdr tool-bar-map))` and finish with `<RET>`. That should output the binding for the separator. (We should have done this first.) Normally it is just `(separator-1 "--")`. (For that reason I asked the previous questions.) But in auctex it is a real noop-binding like `(separator menu-item "Separator" (lambda nil (interactive) t) :image (image :type xpm :file "/home/naehring/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-12.1.1/images/sep.xpm" :scale 1) :help "" :enable nil)`.

Comment: @Tobias Running that line in the `1.tex` buffer yields `(separator menu-item "Separator" (lambda nil (interactive) t) :image (image :type xpm :file "/Users/huihui/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-12.1.1/images/sep.xpm" :scale 1) :help "" :enable nil)` ([the screenshot](https://imgur.com/aN3NxYG))

Comment: Could you go to buffer `1.tex` and try `M-: (setf (nth 7 (cdr tool-bar-map)) '(separator-1 "--"))`?

Comment: @Tobias The separator icon disappears after running `(setf (nth 7 (cdr tool-bar-map)) '(separator-1 "--"))`. ([screenshot](https://imgur.com/hPuo5QG))

Comment: Try with separator instead of separator-1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88178/discussion-between-huihui-li-and-tobias).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Huihui Li](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/19242/huihui-li) pointed out [in a discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48479817#48479817) that separators are not shown in the standard tool bars of GNU Emacs 26.1 with AUCTeX 12.1.1 on macOS 10.13.6.

The strange AUCTeX tool bar separator icon comes from the [XEmacs compatibility package `toolbarx`](https://github.com/jwiegley/auctex/blob/master/toolbar-x.el).

You can turn off this icon by unchecking the  `[separator nil]` entry in the customization menu of `TeX-bar-LaTeX-buttons` (e.g., call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `TeX-bar-LaTeX-buttons` <kbd>RET</kbd> and uncheck `[separator nil]` in the appearing customization menu, afterwards press `Apply and Save`).